# Can't use more general property type in an implementation of an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Say I have something like

```
interface MyInterface
{
     ICollection<string> Things { get; }
}
```

Apparently it's illegal to implement like

```
class MyClass : MyInterface 
{
     IList<string> Things { get; }
}
```

Or is there a way to make it legal?